# How do I get rid of the extra faces created when extruding inwards?

Tags: modeling, faces, extrude

I'm using Blender 2.81a on MacOS.

I am modelling the 'rook' chess piece, and I want to give it the tower shape with cuts in it. When I select the faces and extrude them down, it makes a hollow shape with the edges, vertices and faces still intact.
How do I get rid of these extra faces?

I came across the boolean modifier as a solution but is there any other tool/process that I am unaware of.

[image: My state]

↑ My state

[image: Desired shape (tower with cuts)]

↑ Desired shape (tower with cuts)

Comment: If you are trying to fill the hollow face ,then try (in Edit mode with edges selected)  Mesh > Faces>Fill (or Alt-F)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Blender 2.90+

This feature is available from version 2.90 (https://builder.blender.org/download/)).

It's called *Extrude Manifold* and is located in the toolbox <kbd>T</kbd>, under the "*Extrude*" dropdown, or by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>E.</kbd>

[image]

<sup>*↑ Here I'm using Face select mode (3) but it works in vertex select too*</sup>

---

## Blender Pre 2.90

You are expecting *Extrude* to work in the "[**Destructive**](https://blender.community/c/rightclickselect/Qlcbbc/)" or "[**Push**](https://patents.google.com/patent/US6628279)" mode,<sup>1</sup> *i.e* to be able to remove faces (and portions of them) as well as creating them. Unfortunately, Blender's *Extrude* doesn't currently offer that mode of operation.

For older versions of Blender, namely 2.79, there is a free user-contributed add-on that does that: [Destructive Extrude for Blender](https://gumroad.com/l/cQjUX), but it hasn't been updated for Blender 2.8x.

To model a mesh like the one you're after, you luckily have a very easy alternative: instead of extruding inwards, extrude outwards!

[image]

<sup>1. Using terminology from the Blender addon and from SketchUp respectively.</sup>

Answer (score 3):

If I was modeling it, I would have extruded those 'top brick-like' parts up instead of down and then scale the top part to the right size afterward.
   If you do want to extrude them downward, you would probably need to make a loop cut, delete some edges, and merge some vertices which is a bit more complicated solution to the problem.

Comment: I learnt it the hard way.

Thank you anyways.