# Why are there borders around faces when I extrude?

Tags: modeling, extrude

I'm a beginner at blender and I'm following a tutorial on extrusion but I can't seem to figure out why there are borders when I extrude. I'm trying to make it so that the middle 3 cubes come down together without the borders.

[image: before]

[image: after]

Answer (score 2):

If you create a new file, create a cube, or use default one, subdivide it, select some faces and hit <kbd>E</kbd> only once for every time you want to extrude, there should be no borders around the extrusion:

[image]

It would be a common beginner mistake to press <kbd>E</kbd> a few times this way creating more extrusions so this might be it. You could just start over from scratch since this is not very complex and the objective here is probably more to learn then to save a few minutes.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try version 2.9 (still in alpha as of July 2020)

There is a new function to [**Extrude Disolve and Intersect**](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/162642/92768) that will make exactly what you want to do.

If you extrude inwards it will deal with unwanted duplicated faces.

[image]

Watch this video:

https://youtu.be/FlhAjyLnvrY