# How to extrude a face inward?

Tags: modeling

I made this by following these steps.

Is there any way to model this quicker? Like an extrude inward operation.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/162634/how-do-i-get-rid-of-the-extra-faces-created-when-extruding-inwards/162642#162642

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you're looking for is <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> > *Extrude Manifold*:

[image]

Comment: is that not called "Intrude"? :D

Comment: @Harry McKenzie Yes it should be ;)

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie Not really, because like the "normal" _Extrude_ you can _Extrude Manifold_ in both directions... and the normal one is not called _Intrude_ either ;) Btw, just for info: you get the same result like _Extrude Manifold_ with the regular _Extrude_ if you enable _Dissolve Orthogonal Edges_ in the tool options afterwards (this is enabled by default on _Extrude Manifold_, if you disable it there the result looks like the normal _Extrude_).

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann hey that's actually interesting as well with the dissolve orthogonal option, i will upvote if ever u decide to post it :) EDIT: oh question closed lol

Comment: Yeah, actually already closed when I wrote that comment. 